# Retrieving an array from a JSONArray and setting the array to a class variable

Tags: java, android, arrays

After giving up on gson, I've run into what seems to be a very minor issue but I can't seem to identify the problem. I'm simply trying to obtain an array of integers from a JSONArray and save the array of integers to a class variable.

```
int length = myArray.length();
if(length>0){
    for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
    JSONArray test = myArray.getJSONArray(j);
    myArray = new int[test.length()];
    for(int k=0; k<test.length(); k++) {
        myArray[k] = test.getInt(k);
    }
} 



  // However, when I add myArray to the User constructor, the values don't "stick"
    // ie, 
    User user = new User(x, y, z, myArray);

    // At this point, myArray doesn't contain its values after I try to access them fromthe    
    // User class
```

Here's the User class:

```
public User(String x, String y, int z, int[] myArray){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "User: myArray [" + i + "] = " + myArray[i]);
        this.myArray[i] = myArray[i];
     }
}
```

When I try to print the contents of User, all of the expected values are there except for the array itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any big flaws in your code so I will offer some general advice...

Set some break points in your code and enter into debug mode so you can identify the scope of the problem. Does myArray have all its elements set BEFORE you pass it to your user class? If it doesn't, then take a step back and make sure your JSON array is being parsed and passing you the values correctly.

Another thing I would change is that your parameter for the User constructor has the same name as an internal field. You used the 'this' variable which is good, but you still want to change that parameter name to avoid any possible confusion, you may be assigning the variable to itself.

Setting break points and stepping through your program you should be able to identify exactly where the problem is first occurring and then it will be much easier to solve.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to follow your advice but I still never identified the problem. Ultimately, I replaced the primitive array types with ArrayList objects and that actually made these much easier to debug.